# Apply CSS to even and odd elements following a peer element (table with sub-headers)

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to color the even and odd elements of the table rows following the table row with class "ratingHead". When ".ratingHead" is reached the colors should restart.

[This image of the table may be more clear](http://tinypic.com/r/ng28sp/8)

Here is the structure of the code

```
<table class="evalTable">
    <thead>
       <tr><th></th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr class="tableHeadings"></tr>
       <tr class="ratingHead"></tr>
       <tr class="tableItems></tr>
       <tr class="tableItems></tr>
       <tr class="tableItems></tr>
       <tr class="tableItems></tr>
       <tr class="tableHeadings"></tr> <-- Keeps repeating based on how much information
       <tr class="ratingHead"></tr>    is dynamically generated from the database
       <tr class="tableItems></tr>   <------------------------------------------------------->
    </body>
</table>
```

This is the css I have at the moment

```
tr.tableItems:nth-child(odd) {
background-color: rgb(233, 231, 239);
} 

tr.tableItems:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
```

Comment: you need to show the rest of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to approach what you are trying to do is to use multiple adjacent tables, like this:

```css
.eval h3, .eval td {
    padding: 2px 10px;
}

.eval h3 {
    color: rgb(233, 231, 239);
    background: #5E4F67;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.eval table {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr.tableHeadings{
    background: #9084A0;
}

tr.tableItems:nth-child(odd) {
background-color: rgb(233, 231, 239);
} 

tr.tableItems:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
tr.tableItems td:nth-child(even) {
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="eval">
    <h3>Chapter Heading</h3>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr class="tableHeadings"><td colspan="3">Section Heading</td></tr>
            <tr class="ratingHead"><td>4</td><td>3</td><td>2</td></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="tableItems"><td>odd</td><td>odd</td><td>odd</td></tr>
            <tr class="tableItems"><td>even</td><td>even</td><td>even</td></tr>
            <tr class="tableItems"><td>odd</td><td>odd</td><td>odd</td></tr>
            <tr class="tableItems"><td>even</td><td>even</td><td>even</td></tr>
            <tr class="tableItems"><td>odd</td><td>odd</td><td>odd</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr class="tableHeadings"><td colspan="3">Section Heading</td></tr>
            <tr class="ratingHead"><td>4</td><td>3</td><td>2</td></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="tableItems"><td>odd</td><td>odd</td><td>odd</td></tr>
            <tr class="tableItems"><td>even</td><td>even</td><td>even</td></tr>
            <tr class="tableItems"><td>odd</td><td>odd</td><td>odd</td></tr>
            <tr class="tableItems"><td>even</td><td>even</td><td>even</td></tr>
            <tr class="tableItems"><td>odd</td><td>odd</td><td>odd</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: That works, meaning the odd/even rows will reset in the 2nd table, but if the table layout is fluid, your columns may not be aligned anymore between the 2 tables.  Using 2 <tbody> elements as explained in the other answer will keep columns aligned and reset rows :nth-child().

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that with the current html structure you have.

But you can have multiple `tbody` elements for the grouping (*this way the `odd`/`even` is reset for the `tr` elements under a new `tbody`*)

```css
tr.tableItems:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: rgb(233, 231, 239);
}
tr.tableItems:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
```

```html
<table class="evalTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="tableHeadings"><td>heading #1</td></tr>
    <tr class="ratingHead"><td>Rating</td></tr>
    <tr class="tableItems"><td>row #1.1</td></tr>
    <tr class="tableItems"><td>row #1.2</td></tr>
    <tr class="tableItems"><td>row #1.3</td></tr>
    <tr class="tableItems"><td>row #1.4</td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="tableHeadings"><td>heading #2</td></tr>
    <tr class="ratingHead"><td>Rating</td></tr>
    <tr class="tableItems"><td>row #2.1</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your syntax should be:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #f9f9f9;}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: rgb(233, 231, 239)}
```